# Decomposable measures and Radon-Nykodim derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> A measure $\mu$ on a measurable sapce $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is called decomposable if there exists a family $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ such that:
>
> - $\mu(F)<\infty$ for all $F\in \mathcal{F}$
> - The members of $\mathcal{F}$ are disjoint and their union is X.
> - For all E$\in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ we have $ \mu\left(E\right)=\sum_{F\in\mathcal{F}}\mu\left(E\cap F\right) $
> - If $E \subseteq X$ and $E \cap F \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F} $ then $E \in \mathcal{M}$

I am trying to prove that given a decomposable measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{M})$, and a measure $\nu$ which satisfies $\nu \ll \mu$, and in addition $\nu(A)=0 $ whenever $\nu(A \cap F)=0 $ for all $F\in \mathcal{F}$, there exists a measurable function $ f:X\to\left[0,\infty\right] $ such that  $ \nu\left(E\right)=\intop_{E}fd\mu $ for any set $E \in \mathcal{M}$.

**Here's my work so far:**

First, I proved that every $\sigma$ - finite measure is decomposable.
Then, I proved that given a decomposable $\mu$ on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{M})$, and a measure $\nu$ which satisifes $\nu \ll \mu$, there exists a measurable function $ f:X\to\left[0,\infty\right]  $ which satisfies $ \nu\left(E\right)=\intop_{E}fd\mu $ for any $E \in \mathcal{M}$ which is $\sigma$ - finite for $\mu$. I did it by defining such a funcion on each sub sapce which I chose carefuly from the decomposition $\mathcal{F}$ and then $f$ is just the function which restriction to each sub space is the function that I defined. This is by the way exercise 15 from chapter 3 in Folland's  book.
I am struggling with the last part that I want to prove. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.